# Clear Back Stack Navigation Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I want to Clear my Navigation Back Stack History ...

I tried to use `this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();` but It didn't work.

How could I do this in Windows 10?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're in page code behind, have you tried doing:

```
this.Frame.BackStack.Clear();
```

or if you're somewhere else (like a ViewModel), have you tried:

```
var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
frame.BackStack.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind, you can try this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e){
  if (this.GetType().HasRegionAttribute()){
        base.PopFromBackStackTo(typeof(LastViewModel));
  }    
  base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```